# Unable to use sudo apt update

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm having some issues with my Ubuntu 20.04 server, when I type `sudo apt update` I get the following error:

`E: Malformed entry 2 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list (Suite)`

`E: The list of sources could not be read.`

I've ran `sudo more /etc/apt/sources.list` to see what the issue is but I can't work out which one is giving me problems...

The full log here:

```
admin@localhost:~$ sudo more /etc/apt/sources.list

## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe m
ultiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted univ
erse multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security multiverse
```

I'm hoping someone can guide me on which one to remove so I can use apt again.

UPDATE:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg main
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/

focal-pgdg main
```

Comment: The error isn't in `/etc/apt/sources.list` but in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list`

Comment: Can you update question with content of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list ?

Comment: I will do, hold on!

Comment: I've added the update to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erase the second `deb` line and the rest of the contents in the file.  You only need the contents on the first line to make that repository work.

So, `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list` literally should look like this:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg main
```

and nothing else.

Comment: Thank you for your help!